# How to modify BOOM parameters in ChipYard SOC framework

Tags: riscv

I want to be able to over-ride the BOOM core parameters in my custom config for the ChipYard framework.

I generated a custom config such as:

class KirinLargeBoomCustomOverrideConfig extends Config(

```
// The only argument we can pass (ie n) is the number of cores
// we want to instantiate.

new boom.common.WithNLargeBooms((n=1) => {
    // This is where we now over-ride the core parameters.
    case "numRobEntries" => 156
})                                  ++ 

// L2 coherent cache is included in the AbstractConfig().
// But being over-ridden here with custom size of 512K.
new freechips.rocketchip.subsystem.WithInclusiveCache(capacityKB=512) ++ 

// The AbstractConfig() includes the freechips.rocketchip.system.BaseConfig.
// This is the base Rocketchip system.
new chipyard.config.AbstractConfig
```

) //class KirinLargeBoomCustomOverrideConfig

```
But this generates the following error:

[error] /sim_home/j00533938/chipyard_1.7.1/chipyard/generators/chipyard/src/main/scala/config/KirinConfigs.scala:86:38: not a legal formal parameter.
[error] Note: Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.
[error]       Either create a single parameter accepting the Tuple1,
[error]       or consider a pattern matching anonymous function: `{ case (param1, param1) => ... }
[error]    new boom.common.WithNLargeBooms((n=1) => {
[error]                                      ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed


I am very new to Chisel/Scala/Chipyard.

I read the "Rocket-Chip" tutorial where it gives an example of how to over-ride Rocket parameters and tried to emulate the over-ride of the BOOM parameters.

Any insight as how to over-ride the BOOM parameters?

Thanks in advance
JO
```

Comment: Use might ask in https://groups.google.com/g/chipyard

Comment: Have already posted in chipyard google groups, but got no replies.